# Is there any way to have a background service on Android that carries out network operations at exact times and is not killed by Android?

Tags: android, networking, service, background

I have the following problem: I have to carry out network operations in my app, whereby the execution time has the following restriction:

- There are exactly predetermined times (+/- 5s) at which I have to carry out the network operation.
- The network operation must take place approximately every 30 seconds (the interval depends on the load on the network and is determined during the runtime).
- These operations should always be carried out. If they fail, they shouldn't start again.

I then tried to solve the problem as follows:

- There is a (background) service that performs the network operation and then ends.
- Alarms are set with the help of the AlarmManager, which can start the service at the exact point in time (`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle ()`).

However, the following problems arise:

- As soon as the smartphone goes into doze mode, I get the following error message:
  `W/ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.swp.hydra/.services.RPCService (has extras) } to com.swp.hydra/.services.RPCService from pid=-1 uid=10109 pkg=com.swp.hydra`

Now to my questions:

- Is there any way to have a background service on Android that carries out network operations at exact times and is not killed by Android?
- If not, what are my alternatives?

Possibly still helpful information:

- The app is developed for Android 8.0+.
- The above restrictions are not variable and must be implemented.

Comment: Take a look at WorkManager

Comment: Take a look at the  --https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: "Is there any way to have a background service on Android that carries out network operations at exact times and is not killed by Android?" -- not generally. You are welcome to use a foreground service and some in-process timing option (e.g., `ScheduledExecutorService`). However, your process will be terminated eventually, by the OS or by the user. And this approach, even if you could get it working, is going to be bad for the battery, which is why Android and device manufacturers will be fighting you.